# What are the disadvantages of using POP3, SMTP with Google instead of service like G Suite or Zoho Mail?

Tags: email

G Suite is not free and Zoho Mail free plain has some limitations.

But I can use  POP3, SMTP with Google 100% free.

But I would like to know that what are the disadvantages of using POP3, SMTP with Gmail instead of service like G Suite or Zoho Mail?

Comment: Asking us to list the disadvantages or compare third-party products is off-topic for this site. They're [open-ended](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) questions, without any right or best answer, and therefore doesn't fit our site's format of questions & answers that can be voted on and accepted . They're also open to opinion, and might be considered a [recommendation for sites and resources](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @dan Sometime I think that my question is not clear as I asked... But I don't think that this is a offtopic question... Because I am asking that two different techniques... 

1. Using mail host service like  G Suite, Zoho, 2. Using POP3 and SMTP service with gmail or any other email service like http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/email/email-client-setup/setting-up-gmail-for-pop3-and-smtp .... So I think that I am asking about two techniques.... Then I think it is on-topic here... Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: I understand that you're asking us to compare two different email service options, but that's unfortunately not a good fit for our site. Questions here should be about specific issues and problems regarding operating a website that can be answered _definitively_. The options you're asking about have many differences, and asking users to list the disadvantages or advantages is an open-ended question, without any right or best answer. That makes voting for the community difficult, as well as accepting a right or best answer.

Answer (score 2):

They’re not comparable services. G-Suite and Zoho Mail host email for your own domain. Gmail just gives you a single gmail.com address. If you just want one email address in gmail.com then Gmail is fine, but if you want to use your own domain then you need something more, and there are very few free options.

Comment: We can use our Gmail account to send and receive our domain email address by setting up your domains email address as a POP3> and SMTP account at Gmail... http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/email/email-client-setup/setting-up-gmail-for-pop3-and-smtp... I asked it....

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson You can do that, but it won’t give you different email stores for different email accounts in your domain, which may well have different users.

Comment: There is one reason why you will NOT want to do this. Mailservers are becoming much more strict and performing e-mail rejections. With GMAIL you will NOT be able to configure DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM), and if you use your domain account to send mail from GMAIL, it may not get there.